# Joining array doesn't return string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I'm trying to make a generic toString method that converts both char() and string() into a string:

```
Function toString(ByVal arr As Array) As String
    If arr.GetType() Is GetType(String()) Then
        Return String.Join(".", arr)
    Else
        Return New String(arr)
    End If
End Function
```

Joining the string() returns `System.String[]` instead of the string itself. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're targeting `.net >= 4.0` then there's no need to create such a function. The [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) function has an overload which accepts `Object()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this with overloads instead:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim a() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
  Dim c() As Char = {"a"c, "b"c, "c"c}

  Dim aString As String = ToString(a)
  Dim cString As String = ToString(c)
End Sub

Function ToString(arr() As String)
  Return String.Join(".", arr)
End Function

Function ToString(c() As Char)
  Return New String(c)
End Function
```

Your approach would have worked if you **DirectCast**ed `arr` to an array of string, otherwise compiler picked the wrong overload of `String.Join`:

```
Function toString(ByVal arr As Array) As String
  If arr.GetType() Is GetType(String()) Then
    Return String.Join(".", DirectCast(arr, String()))
  Else
    Return New String(arr)
  End If
End Function
```

But please don't do it like this. Also `arr.GetType() Is GetType(String())` can be just `TypeOf arr Is String()`